# NuGet Package Restore in Bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, bamboo

I am using Bamboo to do the build the ASP .NET project and following steps mentioned in below post.

[MSBuild with Atlassian Bamboo](http://blog.falafel.com/msbuild-with-atlassian-bamboo/)

After running the build I found out it failed on downloading nuget packages and below message appears on summary tab.

*No failed tests found, a possible compilation error occurred.*

[image]

So I looked at log tab and here is what I got

*10-Aug-2016 09:59:09       Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.3.0.1' is not found on source 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.3.0.1' is not found on source 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1' is not found on source 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.3.0.1' is not found on source 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        Unable to find version '2.6.2' of package 'Modernizr'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Modernizr.2.6.2' is not found on source 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        Unable to find version '1.2.0' of package 'Respond'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Respond.1.2.0' is not found on source 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        Unable to find version '1.5.2' of package 'WebGrease'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'WebGrease.1.5.2' is not found on source 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09

10-Aug-2016 09:59:09    NuGet Config files used:
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09

10-Aug-2016 09:59:09    Feeds used:
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09

10-Aug-2016 09:59:09    Installed:
10-Aug-2016 09:59:09        5 package(s) to packages.config projects*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by adding source parameter to my nugate command.

"C:\Users\user\bamboo-home\nuget\nuget.exe" restore "${bamboo.build.working.directory}\atlassianaspnet\atlassianaspnet.sln" -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2;https://www.nuget.org/api/v3"